# Taking data from the table in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code:

```
var attractionDetailsArray = [[String:AnyObject]]()
        let params = ["parm": "getList",
                      "obj": "none"]

        Alamofire.request(adress + "&cos=123", method: .get, parameters: params).responseJSON { responseData in
            if responseData.result.isSuccess {
                if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
                    let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

                    if let resData = swiftyJsonVar["stanyGry"].arrayObject {
                        //self.attractionDetailsArray = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]

                        print("res: \(resData)")


                    }
                    //print("MAM W BAZIE \(self.attractionDetailsArray)")
                    //if self.attractionDetailsArray.count > 0 {
                        //self.tableView.reloadData()
                    //}
                } else {
                }
            } else {
            }
        }
```

The result of this code is:

```
[
  "imieINazwisko": "name and surname",
  "email": "mail@gmail.com",
  "dataModyfikacji": [
"second": 42,
"year": 2017,
"month": 6,
"hourOfDay": 1,
"dayOfMonth": 28,
"minute": 23
  ],
"idTrasy": 18571,
"idxKolejnegoPunktu": -1,
"stanBaterii": 100,
"idStanu": "15490CC0-9590-4A1D-8734-EFB429EF55041501197418.96999",
"idUrzadzenia": "15490CC0-9590-4A1D-8734-EFB429EF5504",
"wynikZakonczonejSciezki": "74 pkt.",
"id": 30764,
"liczbaPunktow": 74,
"czasRozpoczeciaTrasy": [
"second": 58,
"year": 2017,
"month": 6,
"hourOfDay": 1,
"dayOfMonth": 28,
"minute": 16
 ],
 "hashPunktow": "61eee0a94c63af700d99ea0bfc0372d4",
 "aktualnyPunktJestZaliczony": 0,
 "dataModyfikacjiIOS": 1501197822
]
```

How can I get and save to variable: `imieINazwisko`, `dataModyfikacji` (all values), `czasRozpoczeciaTrasy` (all values), `liczbaPunktow` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let say `result = [...] //has all data`

```
if let imieINazwisko = result["imieINazwisko"] as? String {
  print(imieINazwisko) //name and surname
}

if let dataModyfikacji = result["dataModyfikacji"] as? [String: Any] {
  print(dataModyfikacji)
} 

if let czasRozpoczeciaTrasy = result["czasRozpoczeciaTrasy"] as? [String: Any] {
  print(czasRozpoczeciaTrasy)
} 

if let liczbaPunktow = result["liczbaPunktow"] as? Int {
  print(liczbaPunktow) //74
}
```